# ActionScript создание теста

Tags: actionscript

Не работает код во флэш

```
stop(); // останавливаем проигрывание главной временной шкалы

var test=0; itog=0.00; otsenka=0    //объявляем новые переменные

//для подсчета

// количества правильных ответов, доли правильных ответов, оценки

button1.onPress = function() {

// при выборе правильного ответа в каждом из предложенных

// вопросов увеличиваем переменную test на 1

//

if (radio1.selected == true) {                       //правильный вариант ответа 
//содержится в компоненте

//с именем экземпляра radio1

test++;

}

//

//

//

//

//

_root.nextFrame(); // перемещаемся на следующий вопрос

numb.text=test;                   // выводим в текстовое поле number значение

//переменной test

resalt.text=otsenka;             // выводим в текстовое поле resalt значение

                                          //переменной otsenka

};
```

Comment: Поправь объявление
`var test=0, itog=0.00, otsenka=0`
Запятыми разделяй

Comment: Кстати, по-хорошему нужно указывать тип переменной при объявлении:  

    var test:int = 0,
        itog:Number = 0.00,
        otsenka:int = 0;

Поправте меня, если я неправ.

Comment: @Лилит, желательно приводить тексты ошибок, которые выдаются.

@samoilow, только если Вам нужен строгий контроль типа переменной на этапе компиляции. В остальном можно игнорировать. 

Еще я не уверен, что будет правильно работать код около nextFrame при использование главной временной шкалы. Учитывая, сколько она порождала артефактов, использовал всегда контейнер MovieClip.